# How to split items in Python list?

Tags: python, list, split

How can I turn the following list:

```
[['110T148A112', '24,0001100409'], 
 ['110T148A077','24,0001100316']]
```

into

```
[['110T148A112', '24,000', '1100409'], 
 ['110T148A077','24,000', '1100316']]
```

What is the syntactically cleanest way to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: What defines the place to split the second value? Is *all* the data in *exactly* the same format?

Comment: Yes, all the data in exactly the same format

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.findall` to handle greater variability in the positioning and number of commas present in the strings:

```
import re
d = [['110T148A112', '24,0001100409'], ['110T148A077', '24,0001100316']]
r = [[a, *re.findall('(?<=,\d{3})\d+$|^\d+(?:,\d{3})+', b)] for a, b in d]
```

Output:

```
[['110T148A112', '24,000', '1100409'], ['110T148A077', '24,000', '1100316']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the data is in the same format, you could just use a list comprehension with string slices:

```py
lst = [['110T148A112', '24,0001100409'], 
 ['110T148A077','24,0001100316']]


res = [[l[0], l[1][:6], l[1][6:]] for l in lst]
```

Output:

```py
[
 ['110T148A112', '24,000', '1100409'],
 ['110T148A077', '24,000', '1100316']
]
```